# JQuery Masonry breaks after first image, loads with strange gaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I'm implementing Masonry with Infinite Scroll on a Tumblr theme -- something I've successfully done before, but I just can't get this one to stop "breaking" and scattering the images around. Getting desperate!

Live demo at [neuraldamage-theme4.tumblr.com](http://neuraldamage-theme4.tumblr.com) (password is guest).

I've tried removing everything from the body tag except for the #posts div and its contents (and of course the script), but the problem persisted -- so it seems like this shouldn't be an issue with the surrounding divs.

Here's my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#post-video iframe').attr('width', '300');   // resize embedded videos
});

var $container = $('#posts');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.post',
        columnWidth : 300
    });
});

$container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : '#pagination',    // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector : '#pagination li a.pagination_nextlink',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : '.post',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: '',
        img: 'http://static.tumblr.com/6u5yyqj/iUtmgivzo/loading.gif',  // http://static.tumblr.com/6u5yyqj/iUtmgivzo/loading.gif, http://static.tumblr.com/6u5yyqj/yWkmgj1jq/loadingdark.gif
    }
    },
    // trigger Masonry as a callback
    function( newElements ) {
        var $newElems = $( newElements );
        $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems );
    }
);
```

And here's what I have embedded, just made sure it was all up to date:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/6u5yyqj/MPKmktfkv/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/6u5yyqj/nsQmkth3k/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
```

And if you'd like to see the full code: [gist.github.com/neuraldamage/5307289](https://gist.github.com/neuraldamage/5307289)

If anyone could take a crack at this, I'd be greatly appreciative!

Comment: Side note: don't use the cloudflare cdn for your jquery.easing. It's not loading and causes the page to hang.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know -- I'll host it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's running into a bunch of problems because you actually have multiple `<div id="posts">` on the page. Likely a problem with your Tumblr code spitting out more than it should.

Comment: That's it! For some reason it's regurgitating the entire "posts" div multiple times even though it only appears once in my HTML (the HTML I actually paste into Tumblr, not the HTML you see if you view source on the page). It's a total mystery to me why it's doing this -- I started over using the same HTML skeleton (and an older version of the script that I'd successfully used before) and am having no problems this time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this:

```
<div id="posts" style="position: relative; height: 483px;" class="masonry">
```

change that height to accommodate your content (as it's not large enough), or simply don't declare it at all.

When I inspected the element, I simply removed the `height` value and everything moved into place.

Comment: Here's the thing, I don't declare it. There's literally no styling on the #posts div. I've tried using height: 100%, and even absolute positioning, but no dice.

Comment: I was afraid of that. The best option is debug it and isolate the line of the plugin that calculates that value, and then figure out why it's not doing it properly. The quicker (and dirtier) solution is to programmatically change the height yourself *after* the plugin does its business, e.g. in the callback you've set. The dirtiest option is still viable, and that's declaring `#posts { height: 100% !important;}` in your css — This **will** work, but it's discouraged.

Comment: Thanks, but...I tried the dirtiest solution (as the other two are beyond my JS skills) and now they're all sort of blobbing on top of each other. Updated the live demo.